# jQuery Datatables TypeError: aData is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable that uses an Ajax data source. The table is defined as follows:

```
    $("#tblNotes").DataTable({
        "ajax" : {
            "url": "/projects/ajaxGetProjectNotes/",
            "type" : "post",
            "dataType" : "json",
            "data" : {"idProject" : "b92792db-9ea6-49bf-b4dc-1cdf3f441148"}
            },
        "columns" : 
        [
            {"data" : "dComment", "width" : "130px", "orderable" : true},
            {"data" : "cComment", "width" : "270px", "orderable" : false}
        ]
    });
```

The ajax response from the php script is:

```
[{"dComment":"","cComment":""}]
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: aData is undefined
   for ( i=0 ; i<aData.length ; i++ ) {
   -------------^
```

The error is coming from datatables.js (line 15748, col 18).

Here's the source of the ajax source (and the accompanying model function that retrieves the data). Note that this is codeigniter based code (but I don't think that will make much of a difference):

```
function ajaxGetProjectNotes(){
    $id = $_POST["idProject"];

    $notes = $this->projects_model->getNotes($id);

    if(!isset($notes[0]["cComment"])){
        $notes[0]["dComment"]="";
        $notes[0]["cComment"]="";
    }

    echo json_encode($notes);
 }
```

The model code:

```
function getNotes($idProject){
    $this->db->select("*")
    ->from("projectnotes")
    ->where("idProject", $idProject);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $aResult = $query->result_array();
    return $aResult;
}
```

The error is occuring when the page loads.

Any assistance would be appreciated...

Comment: The json returned must have a variable `aaData` that contains an array with all rows.. Maybe you missed that? Would be easier to help you if we could see the json source..

Comment: `[{"dComment":"","cComment":""}]` need to be `{"data":[["",""]]}`

Comment: Interesting. I think I get it. Let me try that and get right back to you.

Comment: Bingo. That was it. I need to place the result inside another variable. I basically changed:

    echo json_encode($notes);

to 
  $result["data"] = $notes;
  echo json_encode($result);

and the error went away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The official [example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_flat.html) explains that flat data sources should use `dataSrc: ''` in the option, and your option would look like this:

```
$("#tblNotes").DataTable({
    "ajax" : {
        "url": "/projects/ajaxGetProjectNotes/",
        "type" : "post",
        "dataType" : "json",
        "data" : {"idProject" : "b92792db-9ea6-49bf-b4dc-1cdf3f441148"},
        "dataSrc": '', // Add this one!
        },
    "columns" : 
    [
        {"data" : "dComment", "width" : "130px", "orderable" : true},
        {"data" : "cComment", "width" : "270px", "orderable" : false}
    ]
});
```